# How to get a word from a sentence using regex nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a use case where I need to get the table name from my sql query 
like suppose I have

```
select * from schema.tableName
```

OR

```
select * from schema.tableName where id = 123
```

OR

```
select column1, column2, column3 from schema.tableName where id = 123
```

In need to get 'schema.tableName' from the sql query in above cases , how it can be done using regex in Node.

I have tried `(?<=from)(\s+\w+\b)`
but I am getting warning that look behind is not supported in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RegEx that will match the table name from queries similar to the ones you provided as examples can be written easily.

Try this RegEx: `/select .* from ([^ ]*)/i`

See the complete code below:

```
var sql1 = "select * from tableName";
var sql2 = "select * from tableName where id = 123";
var sql3 = "select column1, column2, column3 from tableName where id = 123";
var t1 = sql1.match(/select .* from ([^ ]*)/i);
var t2 = sql2.match(/select .* from ([^ ]*)/i);
var t3 = sql3.match(/select .* from ([^ ]*)/i);
console.log(t1[1]);
console.log(t2[1]);
console.log(t3[1]);
```

However, the RegEx will get complex if you would need to match table name from all the possible valid select queries.

### EDIT

You can use a stripped down version of the above RegEx to get the same results.

`/ from ([^ ]*)/i`

Comment: Couldn't you just do `/from ([^ ]+)/i`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, that should work. Thanks. I will make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var query = "select column1, column2, column3 from schema.tableName where id = 123"
var result = query.match(/from\s+([\.\w]+)+\s+/i);

var tableName = null;
if (result && result.length > 1) {
    tableName = result[1];
}
```